# Ionic: Media plugin - can’t get it working

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, media, cordova-plugins

This had been working in an old version of `ionic` but now I've finished updating the rest of this app and gone back to finalise this the sound won't play.

I have an on-off switch for playing a demo sound in the app. Here is the code, with comments and with the commented out part I thought might be causing my problem. It isn't.

```
.controller( 'SoundCtrl', function( $scope, $timeout ) {

    $scope.sound_on = false;
    var media       = new Media( '100bpm.wav' );

    $scope.soundPlayer = function() {
        console.log( "in soundPlayer" );
        if( $scope.sound_on == false ) {
            $scope.sound_on = true;
            media.setVolume( '1.0' );
            media.play();
            console.log( "sound on" );
            console.log( media );

            /*$timeout(function(){
             $scope.sound_on=false;
             console.log("should change");
             }, 12600);*/

        } else {
            media.stop();
            $scope.sound_on = false;
            console.log( "sound off" );
        }
    }
});
```

I get all the right console logs, and I put the wav file in the same folder as my js scripts.

Still nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Is `100bpm.wav` in the same location ?

Comment: It looks like you're using this plugin? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media The console logs will fire because they are independent of any plugin dependent code. I would suggest re-adding the plugin after you've updated ionic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-play-local-audio-files/7479/4) on Ionic forum you have to add '/android_asset/www/' to the path of your media file on **Android** device.

So your code becomes as below:

```
$scope.media = new Media( '/android_asset/www/'+'100bpm.wav',
        function() {
            console.log("[mediaSuccess]");
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("[mediaError]", err);
        }, function(status) {
            console.log("[mediaStatus]", status);
        });
```

In my trial I used a property (media) of the controller $scope to store media object and I attached also successHandler, errorHandler, statusHandler

N.B.: pay attention that `Media` class (function) is already available when you instantiate it with `new media()` in SoundCtrl. It happens to me that SoundCtrl be created before `onDeviceReady` (that is when cordova.plugin.media becomes available), so I added `new Media(...)` to `$scope.soundPlayer()` function.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I don't get where I'm supposed to put the actual file.

Comment: i.e. if you put the file under /www/audio/ you should reference it with `$scope.media = new Media( '/android_asset/www/audio/100bpm.wav',...`

Comment: And now it's working. Why this isn't made front and center in the docs is beyond me. Thanks though. This has taken forever!

Comment: And now it's not working for iOS. I've taken the /android_asset/ bit off, the rest of the app works otherwise, but not the sound :(

Comment: I have never used this plugin on iOS... Have you tried with `$scope.media = new Media( '/audio/100bpm.wav',...` ?

Comment: I've tried a few variations, all trying to point to where the actual file is. nothing has worked.

Comment: Maybe you could check this post http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-add-sound-effects-to-your-ionic-app-with-native-audio/, which suggests another plugin...