# Cordova path to local files?

Tags: android, cordova

I can't figure out what the path is. If i call a file that is on my Device it works:

```
window.plugins.streamingMedia.playVideo('/storage/sdcard0/video/test.mp4');
```

but putting a file in "www/video" it does not work with all i tested:

```
file:///assets/www/video/test.mp4
file:///android_asset/www/video/test.mp4
/assets/www/video/test.mp4
/android_asset/www/video/test.mp4
/video/test.mp4
```

I made a test:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
var sizefilename = path.length - (path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
path = path.substr( path, path.length - sizefilename );
window.alert(path);
```

And the output is:

```
/android_asset/www/
```

But if a look into "platforms\android" there is no "android_asset" folder. Only "assets"?

Now i found this cordova-plugin-file plugin but still can't figure it out.
All i want is something like:

```
var test = document.getElementById('video');
test.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.plugins.streamingMedia.playVideo('video/test.mp4');
});
```

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527664/ionic-media-plugin-can-t-get-it-working/34762706#34762706

Comment: @beaver, but that's for Ionic?

Comment: Ionic is a framework based on Cordova. Plug-ins and Cordova configuration are the same.